# Facebook API changes massive?

Tags: facebook, api, plugins, authentication, socialengine

I don't quite know if my question fits here, but I don't know who else to ask...

I recently upgraded my socialengine plugin, which should allow me login to my site via Facebook. The reason I had to upgrade it because it didn't work anymore since Facebook changed the API (API-KEY --> APP-ID). I think this was around 2010!?

Now I bought the latest version of the plugin, just to find out that it still requires an API-KEY. Their support told me that it's not supported anymore because the version of my CMS is not supported anymore (nice to find that out after paying for it). However they offered me to make the plugin work for me, if I am willing to pay, with a hint that due to the massive changes in the API it will need a lot of work.

To come to my question: Have there really been such massive changes? Has a task like logging into a site via Facebook become that different? I am coming from a programming background, may i be able to fix this myself?

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API is constantly evolving with breaking changes all the time. 2010 is a long time ago for the FB API, so it sounds likely it'll be a lot of work updating the plugin (if the required API features are even still available!)